# Why are the results of two SQL statements different?

Tags: sql

```
 SELECT 0100002562 
 FROM 
     (SELECT KEHHAO FROM FIL_BDSKH) FIL_BDSKH
```

Result：323 row(s)

```
 SELECT KEHHAO 
 FROM FIL_BDSKH 
 WHERE KEHHAO = 0100002562
```

Result：1 row(s)

Comment: Obviously, your first query is giving all of the rows in `FIL_BDSKH`, while your second query filter `FIL_BDSKH` on behalf of your `where` clause. You should see some basic tutorial on sql.

Comment: to be more precise the 1st one returns 323 strings "0100002562", not exactly table rows

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT 0100002562 
 FROM 
 (SELECT KEHHAO FROM FIL_BDSKH) FIL_BDSKH
```

Returns all rows from `FIL_BDSKH`, because you don't have a "selection" by `WHERE`. `(SELECT KEHHAO FROM FIL_BDSKH)` returns all rows, so the non-subquery too.

```
 SELECT KEHHAO 
 FROM FIL_BDSKH 
 WHERE KEHHAO = 0100002562
```

Returns 1 row, because you have just one row with `KEHHAO = 0100002562`. And "`WHERE`" returns this specific row.

Answer (score 0):

think of it as this:

```
select 8 from employee;  // this will return 8 the number of times there are as many 
columns in employee table
```

where as

```
select sal from employee where sal=200;//here the where will filter the rows 
according to the column having value of 200
```

so in your case:

```
SELECT 0100002562 
FROM
(SELECT KEHHAO FROM FIL_BDSKH) FIL_BDSKH
```

this will print the number as many times as there is kehhao getting selected as many rows it has. and

```
 SELECT KEHHAO 
 FROM FIL_BDSKH 
 WHERE KEHHAO = 0100002562
```

will filter the rows having column kahhao as equal to 0100002562 and print that column itself

Answer (score 0):

It is because putting a hard-coded value in select query doesnt mean that it will do a match by default as in your first query

```
      SELECT 0100002562 
      FROM 
    (SELECT KEHHAO FROM FIL_BDSKH) 
     FIL_BDSKH
```

The outer query will print as many times The inner query returns values from FIL_BDSKH. Its not that outer hardcoded value 0100002562 FROM KENHAO will give you when it equals.
while,

In your second query actual filtering is performed in where clause that means Out of 323 rows 1 row matches.

```
         SELECT KEHHAO 
       FROM FIL_BDSKH 
      WHERE KEHHAO = 0100002562
```